# Running rsync from jenkins shell script

Tags: jenkins, ssh, rsync

I'm just starting out with jenkins and I'm having trouble to connect to a remote machine via rsync.

I guess jenkins doesn't know which ssh identity file to use or maybe it knows, but doesn't know how to decrypt it? From other questions i gathered that the Gtk-Warning is probably because it can't open the "enter keyphrase"-prompt.

```
rsync -azvh /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/ofen sascha@my_server:/my_project/ofen
No protocol specified

(ssh-askpass:19928): Gtk-WARNING **: cannot open display: :0
Host key verification failed.
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(226) [sender=3.1.0]
```

Everything works fine when I try it from commandline.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Need to have the key loaded as part of Jenkin's *SSH Agent* configuration.

1. Add the private key to Jenkins via credentials/SSH private key including pass phrase if one is used
2. Enable SSH agent on the job and give it the credential

Things that use SSH keys and agents can now use the loaded key.

Comment: I installed the SSH Agent Plugin. At first i tried to include the private key directly on the credentials dialog, but it didn't work. I copied the ssh-key to $JENKINS_HOME/.ssh and changed the credentials settings to use this directory. Now it works.

Comment: can you expand on this with an example? How would the Jenkinsfile syntax look?

Answer (score 0):

The **"identity"** depends on **where your job is running**:

- when running on the master, it's the user that runs Jenkins
- on a slave, it's the user that you use for connecting the slave

You need to add the public key of that identity to the `.ssh/authorized_keys` file of user `sascha`. This will enable public key-based authentication and `rsync` should run just fine.